# The field of algebraic numbers as a recursive structure

Tags: logic, reference-request, field-theory, model-theory, computability

Is the field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of algebraic numbers in the language $\{+,\cdot,0,1\}$ a recursive structure?

With "recursive structure" I mean the following: There are two recursive functions $\oplus, \odot: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and two constants $c_0,c_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the structure $(\mathbb{N},\oplus,\odot,c_0,c_1)$ is a field which is isomorphic to $(\overline{\mathbb{Q}},+,\cdot,0,1)$. So, the term "recursive structure" is used in the same way as in Tennenbaum's theorem about models of arithmetic.

Here is my motivation for the question: The Abel-Ruffini theorem states that there are polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ whose roots cannot be written as radicals. As a consequence, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ contains elements which cannot be written as radicals. In a rough sense, this can be seen as stating that there is no "obvious" effective system of notation covering all the elements from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. So, my first guess is that the structure isn't recursive and that a proof of non-recursiveness might also involve the Abel-Ruffini theorem. However, it is just a guess. It might well be that there is still an effective system of notation which is not obvious and which bypasses the problem of writing all the elements as radicals...

Comment: Could you show how to represent $-1$ and $1/2$ in the language $\{+, \cdot, 0, 1\}$?  The $\Bbb{Z}$-module $\Bbb{Q} \subset \overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ is [divisible](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisibleModule.html), which I promise is a heavy obstruction to your field isomorphism.

Comment: @Eric: This is explained in the following sentence...

Comment: @AsafKaragila : The *field* has the inverse of the given operations; the *language* does not.

Comment: @Eric: Read the second sentence in the post.

Comment: @Eric: In either case, $-1$ is the unique element satisfying $x+1=0$ and $1/2$ is the element satisfying $x+x=1$. In general, every rational number is definable, so every algebraic number also satisfies a polynomial definition in this fashion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : "$x$" is not in the language; it is not in the Kleene closure of $\{+, \cdot, 0, 1\}$.

Comment: @Eric: I'm switching trains with an underground connection, so I cannot continue this discussion any further. Nevertheless, you should read about "recursive interpretation" of a language or structure in the natural numbers (or some other model of arithmetic).

Comment: @EricTowers I don't understand what you're getting at. Not every element of a field is in general given by a term, but so what?

Comment: @EricTowers It might be easier to look at how to represent $(\mathbb{Q};+,\cdot)$ as a computable structure. There is a bijection $b:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that the functions $$\oplus: \langle m,n\rangle\rightarrow b^{-1}(b(m)+b(n))$$ and $$\otimes: \langle m,n\rangle\rightarrow b^{-1}(b(m)\cdot b(n))$$ are each computable (indeed, **any** of the usual bijections has this property). As a consequence $(\mathbb{N};\oplus,\otimes)$ is a computable structure isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q};+,\cdot)$. The case of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is more complicated but fundamentally no different.

Comment: Note in particular that the relevant isomorphism doesn't have to be definable in any nice way. In fact, to go on a tangent for a moment it turns out that we can find isomorphic, non-computably-isomorphic, computable structures - indeed, very simple ones (e.g. copies of the linear order $(\mathbb{N};<)$). This all belongs to the general subject of **computable structure theory**, for which I recommend [Montalban's recent book](https://math.berkeley.edu/~antonio/CSTpart1.pdf) (but I'm biased, he was my advisor).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The field of algebraic numbers is a recursive structure. I give a brief sketch of the (ingredients of the) proof:

1. You can code each real algebraic number as a one-variable polynomial $p$ and a pair of rationals $l < u$ such that $p$ has exactly one root in the interval $[l,u]$.
2. The set of codes for one-variable polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ is recursively enumerable by a standard argument, so you can encode the data $(p,l,u)$ recursively in a single natural number, and decode it into a triple of natural numbers.
3. By Sturm's theorem (Theorem 2.50 of R1) we can decide recursively which triples of natural numbers $(p,l,u)$ are valid representations of algebraic numbers in the sense that the polynomial represented by $p$ has exactly one root in $[l,u]$.
4. Using standard results on resultants (see R2) and separation bounds on roots of polynomials, we can obtain the following: given $(p_1,l_1,u_1)$ representing the algebraic number $\alpha$ and $(p_2,l_2,u_2)$ representing $\beta$, one can recursive derive some representation $(p,l,u)$ of $\alpha + \beta$ and similarly for $\alpha\beta$, and recursively decide whether $\alpha = \beta$ or not.
5. Now, using bullet point 3, we can fix an enumeration $E$ of all triples of natural numbers that represent algebraic numbers in the sense of bullet point 1. Using the equality test from bullet point 4, we can assume that $E$ is irredundant, in the sense that for each algebraic number $\alpha$ there is a unique $n$ such $E(n)$ represents $\alpha$.
6. Consider two algebraic numbers $(p_1,l_1,u_1)=E(n_\alpha)$ and $(p_2,l_2,u_2)=E(n_\beta)$ representing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Using bullet point 4, we can recursively obtain some triple $(p,l,u)$ that represents $\alpha + \beta$. Define $n_\alpha \oplus n_\beta$ as "the least $n$ such that $E(n)$ represents the same number as $(p,l,u)$". This is a recursive definition. Similarly for $\odot$. Choose $c_1$ and $c_0$ appropriately.
7. It's immediate that $(\mathbb{N},\oplus,\odot,c_0,c_1)$ forms a field isomorphic to the field of real algebraic numbers. Since the real and imaginary parts of an algebraic number are themselves algebraic, it's easy to obtain the field of algebraic numbers at this point.

The best resources for the nitty-gritty details: Cyril Cohen's
    thesis (R2), which has a careful proof on the equality of algebraic
    Cauchy reals being decidable, and a computer-verified implementation
    of exact arithmetic with algebraic numbers; and the book *Algorithms
    in Real Algebraic Geometry*.

---

R1: Basu, Pollack, Roy: [Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540330981)

R2: Cohen: [Formalization of real algebraic numbers](https://perso.crans.org/cohen/work/realalg/)

Answer (score -1):

Responding to the last half of the Question, "an effective system of notation which is not obvious and which bypasses the problem of writing all the elements as radicals"...

You already have one piece of specification: the intended number is a root of some algebraic equation.  So a complete specification is the algebraic equation together with some method to uniquely identify which of its roots you mean.

One method of indicating a specific root is to indicate a complex rectangle the contains only one root.  Another method is to canonically sort roots and indicate which root in the list is the one you want.

[Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html), for instance (almost) does this with `Root[]`s.  The minor difference is that complex conjugates are sorted adjacent.  So the Mathematica rule seems to be that roots are sorted in lexicographic order by real part, then magnitude of imaginary part, then by sign of imaginary part.

Comment: -1. Unless I'm misunderstanding, this doesn't answer the question: the (correct) argument here is that each algebraic number is computable in the sense that its decimal expansion(s) are computable sequences, but that says nothing about the computability or not of the *field of* algebraic real numbers. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ has uncountably many non-isomorphic subrings, so most of them are not "computably presentable," but each individual rational is clearly computable. Conversely, we can whip up a computably presentable subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ with elements with non-computable coordinates.

Comment: (The key to that latter point is that, unlike with $\mathbb{R}$, we *cannot* in general find the decimal expansions of the coordinates of a complex number just from knowing how it sits in the field structure: e.g. there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ swapping $\pi$ and $e$. It turns out that for every $a\in\mathbb{C}$ the field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}(a)$ is computably presentable; now just pick some really weird $a$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber : Meanwhile, I see that this answer exactly responds to the quoted part of the Question.